# Play a sound with QAudioOutput in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, audio

My app should work both on Windows and Linux(Ubuntu). So I have to reimplement my notification sounds, because QSound does not work under Ubuntu.
I am trying with QAudioOutput.

I can't get it to run with this code, and I don't understand what I have to do. Do you have any tips? Or perhaps another idea that works on both OS?

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
import sys
from PyQt4.QtMultimedia import QAudioOutput, QAudioFormat
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFile, QIODevice


app=QApplication(sys.argv) #1st Edit

output=QAudioOutput()

soundFile=QFile()
soundFile.setFileName("C:\\Users\\delete_2.wav")
soundFile.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly)

output.start(soundFile)

app.exec_()                #1st Edit
```

Comment: You may import something like this: `app.addLibraryPath(r"C:/Users/Χρήστος/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/pyqt5_tools/Qt/plugins")
 app.addLibraryPath(r"C:/Users/Χρήστος/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins")`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the only issue, but you certainly need to create a `QApplication` object and start the main event loop. Add this to the beginning of your program:

```
app = QApplication()
```

Add this to the end of your program:

```
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

After the line:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

(before definition of 'output') insert these lines:

```
format = QAudioFormat()  # 2nd Edit
format.setChannels(1)  # 2nd Edit
format.setFrequency(22050)  # 2nd Edit
format.setSampleSize(16)  # 2nd Edit
format.setCodec("audio/pcm")  # 2nd Edit
format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat.LittleEndian)  # 2nd Edit
format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat.SignedInt)  # 2nd Edit
```

and replace

```
output = QAudioOutput()
```

with

```
output = QAudioOutput(format)  #2nd Edit
```

This work for me on Windows, but now I have no linux distro installed to test the code in that OS, anyway I hope it works in both OSs.

Answer (score 0):

There has been changes with these METHODS:

Change `format.setChannels(1)` to `format.setChannelCount(1)`

Change `format.setFrequency(22050)` to `format.setSampleRate(22050)`

See [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudioformat.html#details)